# XMPP Can't get Rosters iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp

i send a IQ request, but i don't get correct result.The back IQ is error

```css
<error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>
```

My code is :

```css
- (void)queryRoster {
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];
    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    XMPPJID *myJID = self.stream.myJID;
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"admin@127.0.0.1"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"127.0.0.1"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"1993"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [self.stream sendElement:iq];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there might be authentication problem. please check your configuration file once again. and one more possibility, if your configuration file is correct then you need to check you have provided proper access-rules on Ejabbered admin homepage.

**Go to your Ejabbered admin homepage -> Login with admin credentials -> in Leftside menu you will find Access Rules tab.**

You will find more information regarding Access rules in below page.

[Access Rules for Ejabbered XMPP](https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc26)

After checked all the detail try with following code:-

```
- (void)FetchFriends 
{
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>"error:&error];
    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"ID_NAME"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"yourid_name@***.com"]; // Try with name in-place of ip like 127.0.0.1
[iq addChild:query];
    [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}
```

And check Server Response in Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
    if (queryElement) 
    {
        NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
        for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Friend: %@",[[itemElements[i] attributeForName:@"jid"]stringValue]);

        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you，but i use openfire server

Answer (score 0):

To get you own roster, according to [RFC 6121 §2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-2.1.3), you need to send an iq to your own bare JID. In your code you send the iq to the JID of the server.

```objectivec
- (void)queryRoster {
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];
    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    XMPPJID *myJID = self.stream.myJID;
    // Don't add a "from" attribute, it is not necessary
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"admin@127.0.0.1"];
    // Probably better:
    // [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[myJID bare]];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"1993"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [self.stream sendElement:iq];
}
```

Retrieving rosters for others is not allowed, hence the "not authorized" error.

Comment: Thank You very much, i get it!